# OpenCV C++ crashes on close

Tags: c++, opencv, crash

I'm working on a simple background subtraction program by using OpenCV `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2`. The codes:

```
int main()
{
  VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
  if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
      return -1;

  Mat frame,foreground,image,edges;
  BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 mog;
  namedWindow("Capture", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

  while(1)
  {
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    if( frame.empty() )
        break;
    image=frame.clone();
    mog(frame,foreground,-1);

    threshold(foreground,foreground,1,250,THRESH_BINARY);
    medianBlur(foreground,foreground,9);
    erode(foreground,foreground,Mat());
    dilate(foreground,foreground,Mat());

    imshow( "Capture",image );
    imshow("Contours",foreground);

    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
  }

}
```

The program works but upon exiting, an error will occur like this:`Unhandled exception at 0xfeeefeee in {prog_name}.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfeeefeee.` and it will point to `crtexe.c` on line 568:

```
if (has_cctor == 0)
  _cexit();
```

Any idea what causes the problem? Thanks in advance.

PS: Currently using OpenCV 2.3.4 and VS C++ 2010 Exp. on Windows XP.

PSS: AFAIK each class/pointer including camera will be deinitialized/destroyed upon exit. Correct me if I wrong.

**Updates(1)**: Still got the error, even after [adding some lines into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582270/contour-is-not-equal-to-contouri).

**Updates(2)**: Tried DEBUG for every line, still got nothing. Tried `delete` function to release resources but cannot find any pointer to use it with `delete`.

**Updates(3)**: It seems like every video processing program I made using `OpenCV C++` will crash on exit, even the one I copy-pasted from books/internet. Changed `break` with `return -1`, still crashes...

**Updates(4)**: I tried my program on another PC (Ms VS 2010 Pro, Windows Vista 64b) and guess what, **NO** crash. Definitely something wrong with my computer's setup...

Comment: Try to use debugger. What IDE do you use ?

Comment: MS Visual Studio 2010 Express. Already tried to debug but no luck

Comment: Just checked your code on linux and it works fine (no crash in the end). In which line does it crash? Or after running? Did you try to put `return 0;` in the end of `main` function?

Comment: Yes, I already put `return 0` at the end but still got the error. I also checked every line possible for error but still got nothing. My gut says DEBUG build in Visual Studio has something to do with this.

Comment: "FEEEFEEE" is "Used by Microsoft's C++ compiler to mark the storage area of a deleted class in debug mode.

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier Meaning?

Comment: That your error comes from trying to access a class instance which was already deleted. However I don't know where in your code is the exact problem.

Comment: The problem is probably in one of your class destructors. Trying to release a resource twice or something like that.

Comment: ok I'm gonna try that.Thanks