# contour is not equal to contour[i]?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

This is based from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578711/contour-comparison-in-opencv-convertion-from-c-to-c), which is focusing more on OpenCV C++ so I decided to make this question. This is one part of my program:

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<vector<Point> > largest_contours;

double largest_area = 0;
for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++){
    double area = contourArea(contours[i]);
    if(area >= largest_area){
        largest_area = area;
        largest_contours = contours[i];  <---THIS is the problem
    }
}
```

Basically [the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578711/contour-comparison-in-opencv-convertion-from-c-to-c) will do:

1. Scans every contours detected in the image sequences/video
2. Labels the contours as `contours[i]`
3. Calculates the area of every contours
4. Compares the `contours[i]` based on the area. The bigger area becomes `largest_area` and biggest contour will become `largest_contours`
5. Finally, `DrawContours` and `imshow`

The line with the problem will show this message over the mouse:

```
Error: No operator "=" matches these operands
```

The question is, **why is** `contours[i]` **is NOT equal to** `largest_contours` despite they have the same class (`vector<vector<Point> >`) and have only one value for each contour at a time? Can anyone explain why and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT(1): Changed `contourArea(contours)` to `contourArea(contours[i])`. Added declaration for `largest_contours` and `contours`.

Comment: Show the declarations of `largest_contours` and `contours`.

Comment: I guess contours is vector<vector<Point>> and therefor contours[i] is vector<Point> - but in any case you don't need to store the contour in full again, just its position in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be getting mixed up between when you have a collection of something and when you don't. I'm guessing that a `vector<Point>` is what you consider a "contour" and a `vector<vector<Point>>` is a set of contours.

As you loop from 0 to `contours.size()`, you are working out `contourArea(contours)` which will be exactly the same every time because you never modify `contours`. It seems to me that you want to work out the area of an individual contour and should be doing something like `contourArea(contours[i])`.

Then, if you want a list of your largest contours, which is also of type `vector<vector<Point>>`, then you need to push each of the contours you find into this `vector`. If `contours[i]` is the contour you want to add to the list, you would do that with `largest_contours.push_back(contours[i]);`.

Comment: Ouch, 2 people already warned me for `contourArea(contours)`, haha. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here, the exact reason for your issues can't be determined without  full declarations, however there are a few things looking odd here:

```
double area = contourArea(contours);
```

This looks like you determine the area of all contours in total - every iteration. This sounds wrong.

```
largest_contours = contours[i];
```

This most likely fails as there's no assignment operator for contours. How about saving the index instead (unless you want to keep the whole structure(?)).

Comment: So instead of `contourArea(contours)` should I change it to `contourArea(contours[i])`? About "saving the index", can you explain more to me?

Comment: I'm not sure right now if that's possible, but I'd give it a try. Saving the index: Just store the value of `i` rather than the contour. If we're talking about simple vectors, you could just insert the contour into the other vector: `largest_contours.clear(); largest_contours.insert(contours[i].begin(), contours[i].end());`